# What is this informal greeting in French containing “forme” and similar to “what's up”?

Tags: anglais, expressions, registre-familier, salutations

I often listen to a phrase that has “*tu*” and “*forme*” in it which is used as an informal greeting in the sense of “What's up”. Can you remind it, please?

This question is linked but I do not find the exact phrase I am looking for here:
[How do you say “How are you”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-do-you-say-how-are-you)

Comment: The accepted answer mentions "Salut ! La forme ?". Isn't that the expression you are looking for?

Comment: How can you introduce «tu» in this?

Comment: By replacing "Salut !" by "Comment tu vas ?" or "Comment vas-tu ?"

Comment: I see, so there is no SINGLE sentence with both «tu» and «forme», then? How would «Tu as forme» sound like?

Comment: You can tell: « Tu as la forme ? ».

Comment: @Zistoloen That wouldn't have the sound *tu*, though. It would be pronounced “*T'as la forme ?*”.

Comment: @Gilles: sentence you have specified is very common but my sentence is also common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is certainly:

> T'es en forme? (Es-tu en forme?)

or

> T'as la forme? (As-tu la forme?)

Both expressions are very common, and rather informal.

It means a bit more than "how are you?". The meaning is closer to **"Do you feel energetic/motivated/excited?"**

The most literal English translation is **"Are you in a good shape?"**

Answer (score 3):

> Comment vas-tu ?
>   La forme ?
>   Ca va ?

Comment: Mon forme est très bien, merci beaucoup :-)

Comment: no you have to answer: Je suis en forme, tout va bien, merci.ici la forme veut dire "la bonne santé"

Answer (score 0):

En complément aux réponses déjà fournies, la traduction habituelle de *what's up* [Cf. Reverso](http://www.reverso.net) :

> Qu'est-ce qui se passe ?

Dans lequel la notion de *forme* n'existe pas.
On entendra plus souvent :

> *Quoi d'neuf*, doc' ?

Familier - C'est la première question que pose [Bugs Bunny](https://www.google.fr/images?q=bugs+bunny&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3Afr%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&hl=en&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ei=tIskUtmIGIq60wWQw4GQCQ&ved=0CE0QsAQ) lorsqu'il apparaît à l'écran, en honorant du titre de *Docteur* tous ses interlocuteurs.
N.B. : En France on n'emploie Docteur que pour présenter ou parler à un médecin, les autres titres de docteur ne sont cités que sur les papiers officiels ou les cartes de visites, sur lesquels on précise la qualité : *[docteur en sciences, docteur ès lettres](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorat_en_sciences)*.

> *Qu'y a-t-il de nouveau,* ?  interrogation de curiosité
>    *Qu'est-ce qu'il y a de nouveau* ? plus soutenu, plus inquisitorial.

***EDIT** suite au commentaire, précision sur la traduction de* what's up

Comment: Malgré l'intérêt intrinsèque de la réponse (bien formulée qui plus est), il me semble qu'on passe à côté du sujet en omettant le point crucial de la question (... contenant "forme" ...). Non ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI J'ai complété les premières lignes afin que l'on évite de faire automatiquement le lien *what's up* et la notion de *forme*. Il n'y a pas de *to you* ou de formule similaire ajoutée, ainsi cela concerne autant (sinon plus) l'environnement de la personne à qui l'on s'adresse que la personne elle-même.

Answer (score 0):

This was used constantly when I played football in the Dordogne.

Simply said like "en forme?"

Literal translation, "on form?"

Feeling well?

I wasn't aware it could be used in a different situation than during sport, evidently, it can.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement

### Ca va

it seems that the expression "Ca va?" comes from an old expression, used by doctor's asking to their patient if they really success to defecate :

Ca va > verb "Aller" > means "Aller à la selle" > pooh

Source :http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salutation#Comment_allez-vous_.3F

With a single googling, it seems this explaination half time is an urban legend, half time a true story ... but there is not any proof ;)

### Avoir la forme / Etre en forme

This expression seems to take place in the XII century.
But once again, I don't find any authoritarive source, just indirects mentions, like here : http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/en-bonne-et-due-forme.php
(Be careful "En bonne et dûe forme" means your a regular regarding the Law / a rule )